# WebSphere Liberty - How to access OSGi bundle services from a servlet deployed via an EAR file?

Tags: websphere-liberty

I have a servlet deployed to the WebSphere Liberty profile via an EAR file. The application entry in server.xml looks like this:

```
<application id="MyApp" name="MyApp" type="ear" location="MyApp.ear" />
```

The servlet needs to access a service provided by an OSGi bundle. I followed the example mentioned [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta/com.ibm.websphere.wdt.doc/tutorials/counterservice/topics/counter_lesson4.htm). The OSGi bundle exports the package the Counter interface is in. Adding an "Import-Package" statement to the EAR's manifest (like an OSGi bundle would have) to resolve the reference to Counter resulted in a class-def exception. So I added the class directly to the EAR. Now InitialContext.lookup() does return a proxy object but typecasting it to the Counter interface results in a casting exception.

I suspect the casting exception is happening because the EAR has its own Counter.class. Is there some other way I should be resolving that reference? How can an EAR import a package from another OSGi bundle?

Comment: Is the OSGi bundle running in Liberty as a Liberty feature or as an osgi application?

Comment: It is running as an OSGi application.